# GA with integer and linear constraints in MATLAB global optimization toolbox

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

According to the documentation of global optimization toolbox "ga does not enforce linear constraints when there are integer constraints. Instead, ga incorporates linear constraint violations into the penalty function".

In an optimization problem, I am trying to solve if linear constraints are violated, other constraints will return non-real values. How can I tackle this issue?

Simplified version of problem

Objective Function : min a + b

```
                 0 <= a <= 10

                 0 <= b <= 10
```

Subject to;

```
                 a*b - 25*a < 0

                 theta < 0
```

Where theta is function of a and b, and returns non-real value if first constraint is not satisfied